# argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable Django error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

In my webapp, I have a friends feature, but one of the if statements produces an error

Here is my UserProfileInfo model

```py
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    connection = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='follow_profile')
```

And now here is my view:

```py
def friend_actions(request,username=None):
    current_user = request.user.userprofileinfo
    user = request.user
    # username = get("username")
    username = User.objects.get(username=username)
    other_user = get_object_or_404(UserProfileInfo,user__username=username)
    # other_user = UserProfileInfo.objects.get(username=username)
    url = other_user.get_absolute_url()
    if other_user in current_user.connection.all():
        current_user.connection.remove(other_user)
    else:
        current_user.connection.add(other_user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

However, this produces the following error:

> argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable

Full traceback

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\interests-site-Ho6yLlHE\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\User\interests-site\interests-drf\mainapp\views.py" in friend_actions
  453.     if other_user in current_user.connection.all():

Exception Type: TypeError at /mainapp/profile/donnellan0007/connect/
Exception Value: argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable
```

I am wondering how I can stop this error from occurring. I have been stumped by it all day

Comment: Replace the `in` check with a query like `current_user.connection.filter(<your condition>).exists()`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug showing up it's face time to time aka Heisenbug!

QuerySet indeed is an iterable (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L271)

Django's Forum has some info about this -

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26600
https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django/issues/117

In General, the issue seems to be because of exception (other than StopIteration) being thrown inside the **iter** .

You can use one of the following routes -

1. Force the Queryset to list (Not recommended)
2. Filter on the connections using a condition. In your case search for other_user in the connection using filter
3. Return values_list of values instead of Queryset and perform 'in' on that.

Comment: `.values_list()` is still a `QuerySet`, which is suspectible to the same issue.